# Can't click "Yes" on "Upgrade Ubuntu"

Tags: upgrade

This seems to be a careless bug, I think.
I can't click "Yes" or whatever other option they require me to click, because I can't move the mouse down there:

[image]

Comment: The buttons are outside the visible area. Click in the top left button (maximize) and it should adjust the window to your screen.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, please report it properly using the `ubuntu-bug` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move the window upwards by holding down the `Super` key and clicking on the window itself and then dragging.  This used to default to the `Alt` key and click, but it's been changed recently.  The setting can be found in `gnome-tweak-tool` under the "Window" tab, called "Window Action Key.

Comment: Unfortunately the window can't be dragged up and still the buttons are outside the visible area. Please read my comment above for a (possible) workaround.